# Pass a PHP variable in a link to a Modal box

Tags: php

Hi i have a html link to a modal box which works perfectly, now what I am trying to do is pass a variable to the form in the modal box, how ever the link shows but nothing happens once it is clicked.

Here is my normal code:

```
   <a href="#accSettings1" role="button" class="btn btn-small btn-primary hidden-tablet hidden-phone" data-toggle="modal" data-original-title=""> Add </a>
```

Here is my PHP code

```
   echo "<a href=\"#accSettings1?ip_address={$ip_address}\" class='btn btn-small btn-primary hidden-tablet hidden-phone' data-toggle='modal' data-original-title=''>Add</a>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use your normal code and add PHP only when you need a PHP variable:

```
<a href="#accSettings1?ip_address=<?=$ip_address?>" role="button" class="btn btn-small btn-primary hidden-tablet hidden-phone" data-toggle="modal" data-original-title=""> Add </a>
```

if it's your application that doesn't work - then debug it first.
Use handwritten example to exercise with. Make it work. And then add a dynamical part using PHP to fill the variable. After that you have to verify if dynamical code produced the same result as a static one. To do that instead of hover you have to inspect *page source* and compare it with original code. Find the differences and correct them.

To me, such an url like `#accSettings1?ip_address=value` looks quite unusual.      `?ip_address=value#accSettings1` looks more familiar to me. Though I am not a JS pro, nor I know your app internals and URLs intention

Comment: Well, it's your application can't handle that click then. So, debug it first, without any PHP implemented.

Comment: but without the php it works fine, once the php is added it stops?

Comment: @user1691024 are you sure that variable actually contains what you are expecting?

Comment: yes when you hover over the button, it shows the value in the task bar on the bottom of the screen, but when you press the button the modal form will not open

Comment: instead of hover you have to inspect *page source* and compare it with original code. find the differences and correct them